# Can we derive the geodesic equation from the Lie derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, geodesics

I have seen everywhere about derivation of geodesic equation from covariant derivative, variational principle but my question is: can we derive geodesic equation from the Lie derivative also?

Comment: Lie derivative is metric-independent, while geodesics depend on the metric. Why would you think those concepts are related at all?

Comment: Yes i agree, Geodesic depends on metric only because we have choose the metric connection for it, but if we choose arbitrary connection without metric then in that case would there be a way to derive such geodesic from lie derivative.?

Comment: similarly, Lie derivative exists independently of an affine connection, while geodesic depend on a particular choice of connection. Why do you expect these to be related?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. As mentioned by [Prof. Legolasov](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/30833/prof-legolasov) in the comments, geodesics are a notion dependent on the connection (which we often determine from a metric when working with gravity). I'll try to give an intuitive example.

Consider the surface of the Earth and a perfect sphere. Notice that the Earth has, for example, valleys and mountains, while the sphere doesn't.

Let us model them as differential manifolds. The sphere is easy: it has topology $S^2$ (which is, by definition, that of a sphere) and metric
$$\text{d}l^2 = R^2 \left(\text{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \ \text{d}\phi^2\right).$$

What about the Earth? In terms of differential structure, it is identical to the sphere. In other words, they are diffeomorphic. We can "flatten" the mountains and valleys of the Earth in a differentiable manner to make the Earth into a perfect sphere. However, notice that their metrics are different, since the geometry of the Earth is different. The metric needs to capture these deformities in the surface of the manifold.

Notice that, in terms of Differential Geometry, the difference between a perfect sphere, the Earth, a bubble of soap, a potato, and so on is a matter of metric. All of them share the same differentiable structure. Notice, in particular, that they all share the same notions of Lie derivative, since the Lie derivative only needs the differentiable structure to be defined.

Suppose now you are a traveler in the surface of Earth with the bold goal of getting to the other side of some mountain. You are not interested in climbing it, since everyone climbs mountains. Instead, you just want to get to the other side of the mountain through the shortest path possible. You took Differential Geometry and hence you know the shortest path possible is a geodesic, so you choose to compute which geodesic(s) will take you to where you want in the shortest path possible.

For simplicity, let us assume the mountain to be really tall, but also really thin. Perhaps it is a kilometer high, but only two or three meters wide.

If the geodesic did not depend on the metric, you'd be able to do this task by considering the Earth a perfect sphere, and hence there would be no mountain. Your conclusion would be simply walk through the mountain as if it were not there, which would lead you to climb the entire mountain, get back down and then get to your destination. That is certainly not the shortest path, because you could have just walked around the mountain and save yourself a lot of walking.

This might be a more intuitive view of why one needs to use the covariant derivative. Geodesics extremize length when there's a metric available, and hence the choice of different metrics leads to different notion of length and different geodesics by consequence. Changing the metric of the sphere to the metric of the Earth made some paths longer, and hence they stopped being geodesics. That happened even though we never changed the differential structure, that is, even though we always had the same notion of Lie derivative.